Calculating Krull dimension of a quotient of a polynomial ring over a Dedekind domain
Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain with $2$ invertible in $R$ and let $u \in R$ be an element that is not a square in $R$. Define $S = R[X]/(X^2 - u)$.
I would like to show that $S$ is a domain, that it is flat and finite as $R$-module and also calculate it’s Krull dimension.
My ideas are as follow.
(i) Finite: Simply because $S \cong R \oplus R$.
(ii) Flat: Let $ \alpha$ be the image of $X$ through $ R[X] \rightarrow S$ (so that $\alpha^2 = u$), from which we see that $R \rightarrow S$ is free with basis $\{1,\alpha\}$. This implies that S is flat.
(iii) Domain: Let $K = Frac(R)$ and consider the inclusion $R \hookrightarrow K$, i.e. the exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow R \rightarrow K.$$
Since $S$ is flat, by definition we have that the function $- \otimes S$ is exact, so we obtain the exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow R \otimes S \rightarrow K \otimes S,$$
from which we obtain
$$S \cong R \otimes S \hookrightarrow K \otimes S \cong K[X]/(X^2 - u)$$
which should be a field since $X^2 - u$ doesn’t have solutions in $K$. So we can conclude $S$ is a domain.
(iv) Krull dimension: by definition dim$(R) = 1$, so
$$\mbox{dim}(R[X]) = \mbox{ dim} (R) + 1 = 2.$$
Since $(X^2 - u)$ is prime, we have
$$ \mbox{ht}(X^2 - u) + \mbox{ dp}(X^2 - u) \le \mbox{ dim}(R[X]) = 2$$
Where ht$(X^2 - u) \ge 1$, since:
$$R  \mbox{ domain } \Longrightarrow R[X] \mbox{ domain } \Longrightarrow (0) \subset R[X] \mbox{ prime }$$
so that $(0) \subsetneq (X^2 - u)$ is a prime chain.
So
$$\mbox{dim}(S) = \mbox{ dp}(X^2 -u) \le 2 - \mbox{ ht}(X^2 - u) \le 1$$
but we also have that dim$(S) \ge 1$ since:
$$\frac{R[X]/(X^2 - u)}{(X)/(X^2 - u)} \cong \frac{R[X]}{(X)} \cong R$$
which is a domain, so
$$\frac{(X^2-u)}{(X^2-u)} \subsetneq \frac{(X)}{(X^2-u)}$$
is a prime ideal chain.
So we have shown that the dimension is $1$.
Does this make sense?
Also, could you please point out, if any, some general results for a ring like this (quotient of polynomial ring over Dedekind domain)?

It doesn’t make sense, as written. S is not the direct sum of R and S

For the domain part, do you mean $\otimes$ rather than $\oplus$ ? I believe your current argument is to tensor the inclusion $R \hookrightarrow K$ by $S$, which does not necessarily remain an inclusion (!) unless $S$ is flat over $R$. You can show this last fact by recalling that flat modules over Dedekind rings are just torsion-free modules. Alternatively, you can show that $S$ is a domain by arguing that $(X^2-u)$ is a prime ideal in $R[X]$, which you can do by hand. Finiteness is ok.

Yes, corrected. Thanks! I will try working on these hints.

$S$ is a free $R$-module, hence flat. There is no issue with tensoring.

Notice that you use in the proof that $S$ is flat over $R$. This is because $S$ is a finite free $R$-module (with basis $1,X$).
Finally, $R \hookrightarrow  S$ is an integral ring extension, hence $\dim(S)=\dim(R)=1$.
